# Fixed element animation scrolls body at top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fixed

I posted this again, but I guess I wasn't clear enough on my problem.

I have a 'hidden' fixed element that I want to open from the side when clicking on it.

Style:

```
<style>
#fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    top: 120px;
    left: -200px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.leftc {
    left: 0 !important;
}
</style>
```

Html:

```
<div id="fixed">
<div id="fixedbtn"><a href=#>btn</a></div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
$("#fixedbtn a").click(function(e) {
  $('#fixed').toggleClass('leftc');
})
</script>
```

So, my problem is that when I click on the button the body scrolls back to the top! I have no idea why this is happening. I have tried using this code:

```
var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop();
$('body, html').animate({scrollTop: windowPos}, "fast");
```

...but I can see the scrollbar move at the top and back to the correct position. I tried removing the 'fast', but no luck.

Help! I would really like someone to also EXPLAIN why this is happening; I have tried everything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's scrolling the body back to the top is because of your href tag,

```
<a href="#">btn</a>
```

"#" is an anchor. Example: If i set my a tag's href to "#myDiv", it'll scroll to the div with the id "myDiv". Since you only put a "#", it'll just scroll to the top.

**edit**

If you really want your a tag to go nowhere, you can try this

```
<a href="JavaScript:void()">btn</a>
```

Comment: Well, I've been into html for more than 10 years, and although I knew about anchors, it never even crossed my mind! Thanks! Another thing off my back! :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking to achieve?

Here is a JSFiddle example for you to look at:  [CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/8qRFx/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="fixed"></div>
<a href="Javascript:void()" class="fixedbutton">Button</a>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width: 0px;
    top: 120px;
    left: -10px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    background-image: url("http://www.cinemablend.com/images/news_img/7768/_7768.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.fixedbutton {
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color:#ededed;
    text-indent:0;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#777777;
    font-family:"Courier",sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    width:100px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}
.fixedbutton:hover {
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
}
.fixedbutton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.fixedbutton').toggle(function() {
    $('.fixed').stop().animate({
        width: "200px",
}, function() {
    $('.fixed').stop().animate({
        width: "-10px",      
    }, 1000);
```

});

I adjusted the functionality that you had from a click to toggle event.  Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for getting into all this trouble to write this, but the above was what I needed! :)

Comment: No problem.  You may want to check out the JSFiddle just for your info.  Thanks.